# how to decode a base 64 encoded image files in ipad aplications?

Tags: image, ipad, file, base64, decode

I am doing an ipad aplication aplication sending scanned photos and signature images that works fine, but while downloading them I have a problem, on sever side they are encoding the image files to base 64 , but I am not getting how to decode the image files at the client side.

Thanks,

Kumar Y R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this posting http://www.cocoabob.net/?p=7

> I use base64 encoder and decoder to
>   put binary data of images into xml
>   data, then transfer the non-text data
>   as text data between server and
>   client.
>
> Here’s an example in my iPhone
>   project.
>
> [base64.zip](http://www.cocoabob.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/base64.zip)
>
> Download these two files and import
>   them in your project and include the
>   head file in your class file.
>
> (Thanks to Jonathan Wight, who wrote
>   it on Mar 18, 2003)
>
> There are four methods in the base64
>   head file.

```
extern size_t EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize(size_t inDataSize);
extern size_t EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize(size_t inDataSize);
extern bool Base64EncodeData(const void *inInputData, size_t inInputDataSize, char *outOutputData, size_t *ioOutputDataSize, BOOL wrapped);
extern bool Base64DecodeData(const void *inInputData, size_t inInputDataSize, void *ioOutputData, size_t *ioOutputDataSize)
```

> Here’s the usage of decoding a string data.

```
NSString *stringValue = /*the UTF8 string parsed from xml data*/
Byte inputData[[stringValue lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//prepare a Byte[]
[[stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] getBytes:inputData];//get the pointer of the data
size_t inputDataSize = (size_t)[stringValue length];
size_t outputDataSize = EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize(inputDataSize);//calculate the decoded data size
Byte outputData[outputDataSize];//prepare a Byte[] for the decoded data
Base64DecodeData(inputData, inputDataSize, outputData, &outputDataSize);//decode the data
NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:outputData length:outputDataSize];//create a NSData object from the decoded data
```

Comment: @kumar can you mark the answer as correct if it was helpful so other will know

Comment: its working in simulator but its not working in device i am getting an exec bad access

Comment: Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)  the above decoder works fine in simulator , in device iam getting above problem.If any solutions please let me know thanks kumar

Comment: can you tell me , iam downloading image files , in server side they are encoding it in base 64, zipping them and they are pushing. at ipad side its works fine in simulator but not in device , application is crashing. thanks